# How to run chromium-browser from the command line?

Tags: terminal, command-line, web-browser

In Linux, when I installed the open-source [Chromium Browser](https://www.chromium.org/Home) I was able to run it from the command line using `chromium-browser` with several useful options (such as specifying a proxy). I've switched to using a Mac and would like to do the same, but I get `Unknown command 'chromium-browser'`.

How would I go about setting this up on a Mac?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To open Chromium from the CLI use

- `open -a chromium`
- `open -a /Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium`
- `open /Applications/Chromium.app` (or the respective path to Chromium.app)
- `/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium` #usually with some errors  (e.g. "Error in event handler..." or some adm_helpers.cc/service_manager.cc errors)

---

Comprehensive list of command line switches:

[List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

Comment: You may need to running `xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Chromium.app/` if MacOS complain chromium damaged.